# How many arguments to a function from OUTSIDE the function

Tags: r, arguments

In R, how can I determine the number of arguments a function expects?

```
fa = function(x){}
fb = function(x,y){}
fc = function(x,y,z){}
```

So I want to define a function, `f`, where:

```
f(fa) = 1
f(fb) = 2
f(fc) = 3
```

and so forth...

Basically, I would like the utility of `nargs()` but from outside the function in question.

The reason for the above, is that I need to know the number of arguments that a function expects, for a specific implementation of `optim(...)`, where the function being optimised is determined and generated at runtime.

Comment: Maybe `formals` will be helpful here. For example, `formals(optim)`.

Comment: You weren't going to use c() as a function name, right?  :)

Comment: `x <- function(a = 1, b = 2)a ^ b; length(formals(x)); # 2`

Comment: @neilfws ha ha. Nice one. Yep, ok, changed the names, cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible approach:

```
b <- function(x, y) {}
length(formals(b))
# [1] 2
```

Comment: Thats the one. Cheers.